# How do I flag a question as being on the wrong site when the correct site is not one of the flag options?

Tags: discussion, flags, site-recommendation, migrated-questions, invalid-flags

I wanted to flag [PNG images look blurry when scaled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36252193/1889720) as being on the wrong site. I tried to flag it as belonging on computergraphics.stackexchange.com, but that was not one of the options.

So I flagged it as belonging on meta and left a comment.

How should we flag wrong site questions if the correct site is not listed as one of the flag options?

Comment: Typically I leave a comment explaining why the question is off-topic for the current site and recommending the more cogent site.  Be cautious in doing so if you do not actively participate in the other site, because sites notions of on-topic are sometimes not as clear as nonparticipants think.

Comment: @gnat yup that's the one. Missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a custom flag (flag for moderator attention) and explain to which site it should be migrated.